# how to trigger onClick event on form_for textarea element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby on rails.  I have a form created using form_for with a textarea.  When the text area is clicked, I would like the height of the textarea to grow bigger.  Coming from an asp.net mvc background, I would think to add an onClick event to the text area and then use jquery to add height px to the text area.  I'm struggling on how to do this using rails:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
    <br/>
    <div class="text">
        <%= f.text_area :notes, placeholder: "add notes here...", id: "tester"%>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I've managed to add an id of 'tester' to the text_area.  I then placed this code in the application.js file:

```
$(document).ready -> {
    $('#tester').bind('click', function() {
        $('#tester').style.height = "200px";
    });
}
```

I got this idea from the rails documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
However this does not seem to be triggering the click event at all.  How can this be accomplished in rails?  Note: I am not familiar with coffee script and would prefer to use vanilla js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer.  My code actually simply had an error in syntax.  Here is the correct syntax for javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#tester').bind('click', function() {
        $('#tester').attr("rows", "15");
    });
});
```

The code I had originally for form_for was correct

Answer (score 0):

Your element does not actually have an id "tester". Rails creates another id for it based on the object you're working on. Try to change `$('#tester')` in your javascript to `$('.text textarea')` and I think it will work.

Comment: this did not work.  But i would also like it to be just this text box not all text boxes which is why I wanted to use an ID.  Can I not apply and id to a form_for text_area?

Answer (score 0):

Bind `tester()` function with `onclick` of `textarea`. When a user clicks on `textarea` the `tester()` will be triggered.

```
<%= f.text_area :notes, placeholder: 'add notes here...', onclick: 'tester()'%>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  function tester() {
    $(this).css('height', '200px');
  });
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add an explanation about what you changed and why ;-)